# React native file viewer No app associated with this mime type

Tags: react-native

> We can preview URL files like this using these two libraries. i am
> trying to read the file url & open that in viewer mode if i use image
> with .jpg it works fine but when i have image from api which is not
> having extension then its not working any help much appreciated

react-native-file-viewer
react-native-fs
Here is the complete code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import FileViewer from "react-native-file-viewer";
import RNFS from "react-native-fs";

export default class FileViewerSample extends Component {
  onPress = async () => {
 

    // Put your url here -----
    const url =
      "https://{{baseurl}}/downloadDocument/2870348";// i have image in this format only 


    // -----

    // this will split the whole url.
    const f2 = url.split("/");

    // then get the file name with extention.
    const fileName = f2[f2.length - 1];
    // const fileExtention = url.split(".")[3];

    // create a local file path from url
    const localFile = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;
    const options = {
      fromUrl: url,
      toFile: localFile,
    };

    // last step it will download open it with fileviewer.
    RNFS.downloadFile(options)
      .promise.then(() => FileViewer.open(localFile))
      .then(() => {
        // success
        // Here you can perform any of your completion tasks
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // error
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          // backgroundColor: 'red',
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.onPress}
          style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", padding: 20 }}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}> App </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

//below is the error

```
error Error: No app associated with this mime type
    at index.js:25:33
    at EventEmitter.emit (_EventEmitter.js:150:33)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:417:27)
    at MessageQueue.js:114:12
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:368:9)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:113:10)
    at debuggerWorker.js:69:58
```

Comment: Is the file from the api always a jpg image? if that's the case, why not creating the fileName yourself? like `const fileName = ${id}.jpg`. And if you don't know the file type from the api, then the api should return a `Content-Type` response header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type, you can calculate the extension from this header

Comment: i know the content type  const fileName = ${id}.jpg after doing this change if i will hit that url in browser i am not getting image then how will do this ? {
    "fileName": "testing.txt",
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "status": "Attached",
    "downloadUrl": "{{baseurl}}/downloadDocument/2870315"
}

Comment: Is `{ "fileName": "testing.txt", "mimeType": "text/plain", "status": "Attached", "downloadUrl": "{{baseurl}}/downloadDocument/2870315" }` the response of api? If yes, you already have `fileName` in it

Comment: yes but with file name if we append with url it will not work its for display purpose only will get image with this format only {{baseurl}}/downloadDocument/2870315" }

Answer (score 4):

Just try to add line in AndroidManifest.xml at the end but before the manifest closing as mentioned below

```
<queries>
    <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <!-- If you don't know the MIME type in advance, set "mimeType" to "/". -->
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
    </intent>
 </queries>
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: You just save my life, thanks!